# How to make two build SBT-ASSEMBLY, using two different config file, within the same project

Tags: scala, sbt-assembly

I'm working on a scala project and i'm trying to make two kind of build (test and prod).

I have two application.conf files ( test and prod) and I wonder how two different SBT assembly tasks that use these files.

This is my application.conf file :

```
app {
  server {
    host = localhost
    port = 8081
  }
  actor-sytem {
    name = prime-radiant
  }
}

cassandra {
  port = 9042
  host = mycassandra.eu
  username = usercassandra
  password = passcassandra
  keyspace = mykeyspace
}
```

My project structure :

[image: project structure]

Thank you,

Comment: I don't know if you can/how to use two different files, but the alternative I use if having one file with subfields prod/dev for each part of interest. This way I am always sure I don't forget something from prod in dev and vice versa. Also +1 to learn to separate.

Comment: can you add a sample project? what is this "application.con" file? has this something to do with sat-assembly or sbt in general?

Comment: And no, application.conf is not a SBT file.